# Sun CertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, security, ssl

I try to get a test running that tests running. As soon as i switch on SSL, i run into the "unable to find valid certification path" error that is pretty common.
My certificate setup is like this:
Test Root CA -> Test Sub CA -> Test Server
                            -> Test Client

So both server and client cert are signed by the Sub CA.
I tried to setup my client and server keystore:

Client-Keystore:

- Client Cert & Key (PKCS12)

Client-Truststore:

- Sub CA Cert
- Root CA Cert

Server-Keystore:

- Server Cert & Key (PKCS12)

I tried to do all variations: Import only client/server cert into keystore, import full CA chain... I always run into that error. I activated SSL debugging in Java, but still this is the last error message i can see.

Could you please help me by taking a look at the log file?
I split it into two parts due to space limitations. 
[Log until first error](http://pastebin.com/99CV51ck) is the first half and shows SSL negotiation and key store handling and shows the first time the certificate path cannot be found.
[Rest of the log](http://pastebin.com/EvYVxrqV) is the rest.

I believe the SSL handshake and certificate validation are ok. When i manually set the truststore like this

```
URL trustStoreURL = classLoader.getResource("jsse/client-truststore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStoreURL.getFile());
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
```

the validation works and SSL is fine. Both truststores are identical anyway. But what does happen if this is not set? I thought setting this programatically (see below) should be fine, but somehow i get the feeling another truststore is loaded (cacerts) that somehow breaks validation. I would really like to understand what is going on and can understand the SSL handshake in the log. I do not understand why certificate validation fails, though.
Thank you!

Edit: 
JAVA-Version:

> openjdk version "1.8.0_91" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Code to configure SSL Context parameters:

```
private static SSLContextParameters defineClientSSLContextClientParameters() {

    KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
    ksp.setResource(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("jsse/client-keystore.jks").toString());
    ksp.setPassword(PWD);

    KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
    kmp.setKeyPassword(PWD);
    kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);

    KeyStoreParameters tsp = new KeyStoreParameters();
    tsp.setResource(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("jsse/client-truststore.jks").toString());

    tsp.setPassword(PWD);

    TrustManagersParameters tmp = new TrustManagersParameters();
    tmp.setKeyStore(tsp);

    SSLContextServerParameters scsp = new SSLContextServerParameters();
    //scsp.setClientAuthentication(ClientAuthentication.REQUIRE.name());
    scsp.setClientAuthentication(ClientAuthentication.NONE.name());

    SSLContextParameters sslContextParameters = new SSLContextParameters();
    sslContextParameters.setKeyManagers(kmp);
    sslContextParameters.setTrustManagers(tmp);
    sslContextParameters.setServerParameters(scsp);


    return sslContextParameters;
}

private static SSLContextParameters defineServerSSLContextParameters() {
    KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
    ksp.setResource(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("jsse/server-keystore.jks").toString());
    ksp.setPassword(PWD);

    KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
    kmp.setKeyPassword(PWD);
    kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);

    KeyStoreParameters tsp = new KeyStoreParameters();
    tsp.setResource(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("jsse/server-truststore.jks").toString());
    tsp.setPassword(PWD);

    TrustManagersParameters tmp = new TrustManagersParameters();
    tmp.setKeyStore(tsp);

    SSLContextServerParameters scsp = new SSLContextServerParameters();
    //scsp.setClientAuthentication(ClientAuthentication.REQUIRE.name());
    scsp.setClientAuthentication(ClientAuthentication.NONE.name());

    SSLContextParameters sslContextParameters = new SSLContextParameters();
    sslContextParameters.setKeyManagers(kmp);
    sslContextParameters.setTrustManagers(tmp);
    sslContextParameters.setServerParameters(scsp);


   return sslContextParameters;
}
```

Code that configures my test route:

```
@Override
protected RouteBuilder[] createRouteBuilders() throws Exception {
    RouteBuilder[] rbs = new RouteBuilder[2];

    // A consumer
    rbs[0] = new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {

            // Needed to configure TLS on the client side
            WsComponent wsComponent = (WsComponent) context.getComponent("idsclient");
            wsComponent.setSslContextParameters(defineClientSSLContextClientParameters());

            from("direct:input").routeId("foo")
                .log(">>> Message from direct to WebSocket Client : ${body}")
                .to("idsclient://localhost:9292/echo")
                .log(">>> Message from WebSocket Client to server: ${body}");
            }
    };

    // A provider
    rbs[1] = new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {

                // Needed to configure TLS on the server side
                WebsocketComponent websocketComponent = (WebsocketComponent) context.getComponent("idsserver");
                websocketComponent.setSslContextParameters(defineServerSSLContextParameters());

                // This route is set to use TLS, referring to the parameters set above
                from("idsserver:localhost:9292/echo")
                .log(">>> Message from WebSocket Server to mock: ${body}")
                .to("mock:result");
        }
    };
    return rbs;
}
```

The test cert for the server side looks like this (taken from the log file):

```
found key for : server
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Test Server, OU=MyDepartment, O=MyCompany, L=Munich, ST=Bavaria, C=DE

  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 19697468346206325338625931027401620685505412743602335229201285324147237256216294710834287613270808792700765169197171367371459991031662084309764776191914171160104989266207613238184784158415975037177065022201531172433794931849866898549526682368884371139417838799836320672154199909478730633522432282118939559532307066108447566990979134741165253612506513491626459651819946324249745973578011579650517987718802720162457248935339641095429277723082345377268006775487733517858798408645354401260091015110745708667097965877142342305591846833532604648462225727819942287641383438004739414038605341137460966856052237012367021734999
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue Oct 25 09:37:42 CEST 2016,
               To: Thu Oct 25 09:37:42 CEST 2018]
  Issuer: CN=Test SubCA 2016, O=Company, C=DE
  SerialNumber: [    01]

Certificate Extensions: 6
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: A5 55 EC 7E AC F0 98 95   EA 58 D7 BF 43 92 2C 65  .U.......X..C.,e
0010: AA A0 32 73                                        ..2s
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  clientAuth
  serverAuth
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: localhost
  DNSName: 127.0.0.1
]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 7F 45 12 3E F5 17 F8 EF   FF 2F 08 46 25 4B 21 60  .E.>...../.F%K!`
0010: EB FC 1B 4F                                        ...O
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
```

Comment: In the future, you should state the Java version, provide the relevant code and provide a stack trace with the relevant exception information. You should also provide the server's certificate. Otherwise, there's not much we can do to help you.

Comment: Ok, sorry, maybe i was not clear enough. I provided the missing information. As i do more and more debugging, i have the feeling the problem does not come from the SSL handshake. The problem immediately vanishes if i manually set the truststore property. Added that information.